# Are vector field swith a saddle connection always stucturally unstable?

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields, perturbation-theory

I'm interested in dynamical systems, but I don't have a very solid mathematical background. I know that in 2D, Peixoto's theorem gives a characterization of structurally stable vector fields. Even if it's not generalizable in greater dimension, do we know if there exist some structurally stable vector fields with a homoclinic orbit, for instance ?